# Why isn't this ListView binding to this list?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ViewModel and a XAML view which don't seem to be binding in this particular case (other bindings across this View and same ViewModel are working already). Roughly, the setup has

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public List<IntegrationListItem> RightPanelViewModels { get; set; }

    MainViewModel()
    {
        RightPanelViewModels = new List<IntegrationListItem>();
    }

    private void ButtonPush()
    {
        ViewModels.Add(new SomeIntegration());
    }
}

public class IntegrationListItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SomeIntegration : IntegrationListItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    SomeIntegration()
    {
        Name = "XXXX";
    }
}
```

View:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RightPanelViewModels}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My problem is when I trigger ButtonPush() (and I've verified that it is indeed being triggered), nothing happens where the ListView should be. My apologies if this isn't a MCV example, but I'm really at a loss of what I'm missing. I've been following [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/) tutorial and they make it seem extremely simple.

Comment: Use ObservableCollection, not List. ObservableCollection raises notification events when you add items.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Well that was easy. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: As @EdPlunkett said, or either use a `BindingSource`, and whenever you must update your ListBox just do `BindingSource.ResetBindings()`

Comment: @NilsGuillermin It's such a FAQ, I've picked up those same 15 pokeymon points a million times already by now. Hardly seems right.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Found a good dupe target for the next time you see it :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks! I can't ever find anything around here.